# Echo never display blank text content from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I know it must be something simple but I can't do

I need display the text into a `<div>`

Like this:

```
<div>
<p><font color="#bdbdbd">TEXTO FROM MYSQL</font></p>
</div>
```

My table structure is:

```
id  int(11)  Nulo: Não   Padrão:Nenhum  AUTO_INCREMENT
depoimento  varchar(255)    utf8_unicode_c… NULL
client varchar(60)  utf8_unicode_ci  Nulo:Sim   Pa… NULL
```

I'm trying this:

```
$db['server']   =   'localhost';
$db['user']  =  '**';
$db['password'] =   '***';
$db['dbname']   =   '**********';

$conn = mysql_connect($db['server'],$db['user'],…
mysql_select_db($db['dbname'],$conn);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM opinions ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql)
while ($linha=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
$depoimento = $linha["depoimento"];
$client = $linha["client"];
echo "$depoimento";
echo "$client";
} 
?>
```

But it still appearing blank
I'm using a SEMI DEDICATED SERVER (VPS)

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe you have empty fields

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after `mysql_query($ql)`. Is that in your real code?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to put `;` at the end of `$resultado = mysql_query($sql)`.

Comment: Please don't use the deprecated font tag, do this instead: `<p style="color:#bdbdbd;">TEXTO FROM MYSQL</p>`, and give the div or p element an id so you can target it with JavaScript.

Comment: Error logs don't say anything, i EVER get a blank page.
Doesn't matter if i put ini_set( 'display_errors', true );
error_reporting( E_ALL ); , always blank page, what is happening?

Comment: You asked this and it was closed... [ECHO MYSQL RESULT DISPLAY BLANK PAGE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733054/echo-mysql-result-display-blank-page)

Answer (score 0):

```
$resultado = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
```

Try telling the query which connection resource to use, also some well placed var_dumps will help debug the code.

```
while ($linha=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {

var_dump($linha); exit;

$depoimento = $linha["depoimento"];
$client = $linha["client"];
echo "$depoimento";
echo "$client";
}
```