# ECHO MYSQL RESULT DISPLAY BLANK PAGE

Tags: php, mysql, html

I know it must be something simple but I can't do

I need display the text into a DIV

Like this:

```
<div>
  <p><font color="#bdbdbd">TEXTO FROM MYSQL</font></p>
</div>
```

My table structure is:

```
id          int(11)         Nulo: Não   Padrão:Nenhum  AUTO_INCREMENT
depoimento  varchar(255)    utf8_unicode_c…  NULL
client      varchar(60)     utf8_unicode_ci  Nulo:Sim   Pa… NULL
```

You can see my code in action here: loja.genesiseries/depoimentos/testemysql.html

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM opinions ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql);

while ($linha=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
    $depoimento = $linha["depoimento"];
    $client = $linha["client"];
    echo "$depoimento";
    echo "$client";
}
?>
```

But it still appearing in blank I'm using a SEMI DEDICATED SERVER (VPS)

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Php and html are different....

Comment: How your comment should help me Deepu?

Comment: reading [manual](http://php.net/echo) should help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename `loja.genesiseries/depoimentos/testemysql.html` to `loja.genesiseries/depoimentos/testemysql.php`

```
<div>
    <p>
        <font color="#bdbdbd">
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM opinions ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15";
            $resultado = mysql_query($sql);
            while ($linha=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
                $depoimento = $linha["depoimento"];
                $client = $linha["client"];
                echo "$depoimento";
                echo "$client";
            }
            ?>
        </font>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ian Brindley!!

Comment: But is there any way to add this code into a HTML page?

Comment: @user2415711 No. the page needs to be a php file. You can however use mod_rewrite to make it seem like a `.html` file in the address bar